# infowindow.close() does not act with multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I read a lot of solutions and tried several but in my script I can not getting it done.

I like to close the active infowindow when another marker is clicked.

Part of the code:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var centrum = locations[i];
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(centrum[1], centrum[2]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              icon: image,
              shape: shape,
              title: centrum[0],
              zIndex: centrum[3]
          });
          marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<b>Informatie:</b><br>' + centrum[0]
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              marker['infowindow'].close(); // has to close another active window
              this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
          });
        }
```

Someone a hint or better... a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep markers in an array and add a call for a function to close all windows before opening the current one:

```
function closeInfos() {
    for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++)
    {
        markers[i]['infowindow'].close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

With your code, it should look something like that:

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var centrum = locations[i];
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(centrum[1], centrum[2]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              icon: image,
              shape: shape,
              title: centrum[0],
              zIndex: centrum[3]
          }));
          marker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<b>Informatie:</b><br>' + centrum[0]
          });
          markers.push(marker);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              closeInfos();
              this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
          });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried Mauno V. solution allready and it works.

Comment: Hmmm, I will try your solution but can not figure it all out. Would you please adjust my code to work with your solution...

Answer (score 1):

Keep only one reference to infowindow by storing it to variable like:

`var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "some text here..."});`

thats the way to do it, now you are creating many intances of that class..

Check out full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWPVJ/1/)

**Edit:**

Infowindows with unique content [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWPVJ/2/)

Comment: OK, thanks, I changed the code according your fiddle and it works.

Comment: OH no... it is not working after testing live... the infoWindows gives all the sameinformation now in stead of per centrum...

Comment: yea, sorry, i was already afk when you was having problems.. you could have adjusted the content of infowindow too by setting for example content values to markers when they are created. I added another fiddle to display that. Reason why my code is better than Philippe, is that I am not creating unnecessary amounts of objects (info windows) which are needed to loop through to be closed, program will slow when number of markers increases, mine doesn't.